# Bash script delete folders total size

Tags: bash

I am hoping to run a bash script that pretty much delete any folder inside `/storage/*` that has a total size that is less than 5 megs. Issues I face is that the folders inside `/storage/*` has sub sub sub folders as well. I want to delete it all if it's less than 5 megs... So far I have the below commands, any kind of further help I can get to finish this script is greatly appreciated!

```
$ find /storage/ -type f -size -5M -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what it will delete, remove the line `rm -rf $filename;`

```
du -s ./storage/* | while read size filename; do if [ $size -lt 5120 ]; then echo "Deleting $filename"; rm -rf $filename; fi; done
```

**UPDATE:** This will not delete any files inside `storage`. If you want to see what it will delete, remove the line `rm -rf $filename;`.

```
du -s ./storage/*/ | while read size filename; do if [ $size -lt 5120 ]; then echo "Deleting $filename"; rm -rf "$filename"; fi; done
```

Comment: How can i just make it list the folders it will delete for now so I can double check to see if this command works? I don't won't it to wipe out my entire folder underneath /storage/

Comment: I noticed this will delete my script files in the folder /storage folder as well... anyway we can exclude a few folders/filenames that we don't want to be deleted?

Comment: If you use `./storage/*/` as the wildcard, this will only pick up folders and you can avoid the `&& [ -d $filename ]` test. (You sould really quote `$filename` properly if you are going to run `rm -rf` on it!)

Comment: @bobbogo - I'm still learning, and I always forget quotes. Updated!

Comment: Thank you so much, i'v been testing, but it seems like it keep on deleting any file with .sh .php in the sub directories, is there anyway we can eliminate this?

Comment: So you want to exclude all files or just the files ending with `.sh` and `.php`?